# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.99

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I bought this app code in codecanyon, but the author is not answering. That's why I am asking here. I don't know about android, I'm simply following their tutorial. Here is the my problem. Can any one please help?

gradle version
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

This is the error I am getting

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.99
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app

Comment: There is no firebase-core version 17.3.99. The latest versions of all the Firebase libraries are listed here.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android, there are the latest firebase release. About firebase-core, latest version is 17.2.1. 
as i saw in you app level build.gradle you use "compile" for your dependencies, you should change all this compile by implementation and update you're dependencies version to the latest release like that

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.2'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

}
```

you should also use the latest release of google-services ; update your project-level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

update gradle version in gradle.properties file:

```
#Mon May 21 12:39:33 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

you can find all the firebase setup here https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: if i change fire base version it will work 17.3.99 to 17.2.1 it will work ? or do need do any extra things?

Comment: normally it will work but the best for you is to upload here your gradlew files as we can see if thre is no more problem

Comment: Hi i don't know knowledge about android i bought this source code in codecanyon, but the author is not answering. i don't have time to day i have to make this app if don't mind can you change it please its my humble request. or there is any video tutorial how to change this i fallow that

Comment: i gave you all what you need to resolve your problem you juste have to edit two files i cannot make more thing for use if you're incapable to do that. have a nice day

Comment: ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.4.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle settings
now getting this error what have to do now @SebastienRieu

Comment: you just have to update the gradle version in gradle.properties file in root project directory. please see the update of my response. I suggest to upgrade the gradle version to the latest ; 5.4.1

Comment: Thank you for help @Sbastienrieu every thingy i changed like your examples but one thing i cant find them where it is available i meand witch file implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'

Comment: i don't understand ? chat's the problem ?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1' –                                   
 In witch file i have to change this

Comment: i understand, i've removed the first line in my response. u just have to put the first part of code in the dependencies section of src/app/build.gradle (call the "app level build.grable file) and the second part of code in the dependencies section of src/build.gradle (called the "project level build.gradle file). it will works. All dependencies in your project are always in the two build.gradle files.

Comment: Now getting like this error https://ibb.co/f1Kqbdk
https://ibb.co/8K70w7w

Comment: the problem is at line 68 can you post this ?

Comment: there's an error in this file, it missed '}', i cannot find this error for you !!!!

Comment: Now getting line 29 error can you please check it once https://ibb.co/2KFdRW3

Comment: the error is in the other build.gradle....... ! that's why is red-underline in android studio ...... !

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRduJl-IGEYfJeUXL65m7PocryjR50Gw/view?usp=sharing